# Trying to pass two dictionaries but only first one works

Tags: django

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'title': 'HOME'}, {'post': posts})
```

In this code, only **title** works. when I took {'post': posts} before {'title': 'HOME'} , post works but title don't. 
I have to use both in templates. I'm a beginner in django. How can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one context dictionary, but a dictionary can have as many key/values as you want.

```
 def home(request):
      context = {'title': 'HOME','post': posts}
      return render(request, 'blog/home.html',context)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
{
    'title': 'HOME',
    'post': posts
}
```

This way, both variables are part of the same object.

It's crucial to put both values to the same data structure, because in your code, `post` was a fourth parameter, which is reserved [for a different functionality.](https://devdocs.io/django~2.2/topics/http/shortcuts#django.shortcuts.render)

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass one dictionary as the context for the page.

```
def home(request):
    context = {'title': 'HOME',
               'post': posts }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Django's `render` function takes only one positional argument for context. that's why your first dictionary is working and the second one is chopped off as Django take fourth positional argument as `content_type`

```
render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)
```

ref : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/

So you should pass only one object of dictionary with all your desired data. it can have nested object.

```
 def home(request):
    context_data = {'title': 'Home',
                   'post': posts }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context_data)
```